# How can I send images via whatsapp from my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, image, camera

I am writing a camera application for iPhone, and I want to send edited images via Whatsapp Messenger.

How can I send images via whatsapp messenger from my own application?

Comment: i don't think there are any public API provided by WhatsApp messenger application. So it's not possible

Comment: ok. is it possible to launch whatsapp in my application through URL Schema? do you know URL Schema for whatsapp?